# C++: what is wrong with abs

Tags: c++

After a long time trace of my program I finally found that `abs` is the blameable part of my program. What should I expect from this code? why do I get:

> x=0.1
>
> |x|=0

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double x=0.1;
    std::cout<<"x="<<x<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"|x|="<<abs(x)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `abs` is an integer function, try `std::abs` which has overloads for different types.

Comment: @JonathanPotter There are two different `abs` functions, [one in `cstdlib`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/), [one in `cmath`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/). Both can be referenced with the `std::` prefix.

Comment: If this is the real code then probably what happened is that `iostream` included `cstdlib` but not `cmath` on OP's system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the [`abs` defined in `<cstdlib>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/), which only works on integers.

Use the [`abs` defined in `<cmath>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/) instead. It works on floating point values.

Comment: so I am wondering why [here](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/59282c85551168b7cba721ed17f9aecdf227b558/include/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/default_operations.hpp) line 516 `abs` is ok!

Comment: @ar2015: Presumably because they included the `<cmath>` header.

Comment: but how to know which `abs` is being called? function overload?

Comment: If both headers are included the only way to know which one gets called is to look at the type of the parameter.

Answer (score 7):

You may be wondering "But why I didnt get warning on `g++ -g -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wextra -std=c++11 test.cpp -o ./bin/test -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system`?"

[Turns out `Wall` isn't quite "all".](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion)

```
 g++ -g -Wconversion -std=c++11 test.cpp -o tester -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:7:29: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     std::cout<<"|x|="<<abs(x)<<std::endl;
                             ^
```

`clang-3.6`'s diagnostic is clearer still, and no explicit opt-in required:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o tester
test.cpp:8:24: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
    std::cout<<"|x|="<<abs(x)<<std::endl;
                       ^
test.cpp:8:24: note: use function 'std::abs' instead
    std::cout<<"|x|="<<abs(x)<<std::endl;
                       ^~~
                       std::abs
test.cpp:8:24: note: include the header <cmath> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'std::abs'
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: In gcc, -Wnarrowing would catch this.